# Spring Boot Delete controller returns 204 , but does not delete data from the database

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, crud, spring-restcontroller

Following is my code to delete an existing row from the checklist table.

On sending request spring returns 204.

But the data does not get deleted from the database.

On doing a get request I still get the data that I wanted to be deleted.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
        @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public void deleteChecklist(@PathVariable("id") Long checklistId) throws ChecklistResourceNotFoundException {
            Checklist checklist = RestPreconditions.checkFound(checklistRepository.findOne(checklistId));
            checklistRepository.delete(checklist);
        }

@Repository
public interface ChecklistRepository extends CrudRepository<Checklist, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us implementation of `ChecklistRepository`?

Comment: Edited the question @nowszy94

Comment: @A.S the Checklist entity has association with other entity?

Comment: Are you using what version of spring-boot?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)`. No wonder Spring returns 204. But ideally it should have deleted the entry. Just verify the call to get data from repo actually returns the Checklist entity. If it does, then the delete should be working provided you have DB level privilege to do so.